# mysql - want to group by two columns including by each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql 5.5 query:

```
select  count(original_url), original_url  from page_views group by original_url order by count(original_url) desc;
```

but would also like to group by each day (like 2014-06-23) so that I can see which day has the most page_views per url. It's a rails app so there is a created_at. I was thinking something like:

```
select  count(original_url), original_url, created_at from page_views group by original_url, created_at order by count(original_url) desc;
```

but that selects and groups by hour:min:sec and I just want it to be by day like YEAR-MONTH-DAY. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Date function:

```
select  count(original_url), original_url, created_at from page_views group by original_url, DATE(created_at) order by count(original_url)
```

Comment: thx - that is what I was looking for; have to wait  a few minutes